# Execute method when user leaves and then starts application

Tags: android

I have a question about the android lifecycle. This is my **onCreate** method of my main application:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    decode = new Decode(this);

    adjustToDimensions();
    setLoadingScreen("Zorgdossier wordt geladen...");
    initReceiver();
    startCommunicationWithServer();
}
```

I set the screen to a loading screen, initialize a broadcastReceiver and send a message to the server.

Now, when I press the home button and start my application again I always want to start this activity so I've added

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

To the manifest.

But now I want the **startCommunicationWithServer**() to be executed when the user starts the application again. This method sends a message to the server, and the server on the other hand sends a message that I receive in the receiver. 
With this message I decide which screen to show.

I've tried to put it in the **onRestart** method:

```
    @Override
protected void onRestart() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "activity restarted");
    startCommunicationWithServer();
    super.onRestart();
}
```

But this activity is shown multiple times troughout the application, so the onRestart method is executed each time. But I only need the **startCommunicationWithServer**() to be executed at the start of the application.

So long story short, how can I call the **startCommunicationWithServer**() method when the user exits and subsequently starts my application?

Comment: what's wrong with your onCreate?

Comment: the onCreate method isn't called when I exit and then open the application. Should it be called normally? or did I place my android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" on the wrong place?

Comment: Are you targeting SDK level 11 or above? In that case do have a look at [recreate() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29).

Comment: Do it in your `onResume` merhod... Of course, then it will happen whenever the activity goes out of sight...